# Gesture recognition in C#

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I don't know unity but I know c#
there is a game https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6DYwnXBXYI and I need to make the same
how to make this gesture recognition?

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful in setting up your own custom gestures:
https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript

Otherwise if you want to give it a go yourself, have a look at the touch variables and functions in the Unity Input class:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html